# reset button in angular js

Tags: angularjs, radio-button, radiobuttonlist

I have a "clear" button, once user hit it all the data in container,all binding and the radio buttons should be reset (like initially). Currently only the view becomes empty but the container has still the old value. How can I fix it?

```
<div class="field">
         <textarea name="price" ng-model="list.price"></textarea>
</div>

 <input type="radio" ng-model="list.phone" value="1" />cell
 <input type="radio" ng-model="list.phone" value="2" />home

<button class="btn btn-primary btn-large center" type="reset"  ng-click="">
                        Clear
</button>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Set `ng-click` to some function, say `reset()`

```
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-large center" 
        type="reset" 
        ng-click="reset()">Clear
</button>
```

and then set the model to an empty object

```
$scope.reset = function() {
    $scope.list = {};
}
```

Or, if $scope.list is prepopulated, you could do something like this (taken from angular docs):

```
function Controller($scope) {
    $scope.master = {};

    $scope.reset = function() {
      $scope.list = angular.copy($scope.master);
    };

    $scope.reset();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, how about radio buttons? how to reset them?

Comment: This would reset the radio buttons in your example [jsBin](http://jsbin.com/howetozi/3/edit)

Comment: Thanks Tom. I don't why people gave me -1:(