# Unable to change variable value attached to scope in angular js?

Tags: angularjs

value of $scope.user.name should be changed to 'please enter name' , i should get 'please enter name' when click on reset button.

```
$scope.user = {};
$scope.reset =function(dta){
       $scope.dta = 'please enter name';
     }

       <input type ="text" ng-model="user.name">

       <button ng-click="reset('user.name')">Reset</button>
```

Comment: What exactly you are trying?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22459914/reset-button-in-angular-js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass object and property separately, not as a single string.

And it is much better to use attribute `placeholder` instead of applying it to the object.

https://jsfiddle.net/wtq0mmgj/1/

**UPDATE:**

passing `user.name` without `''` won't work because you apply value to `$scope.dta` instead of target object, so you'll be able to see the value in `{{dta}}`, but not in `{{user.name}}`

Answer (score 2):

Just remove `''` from `user.name`

Convert this

```
<button ng-click="reset('user.name')">Reset</button>
```

to this

```
<button ng-click="reset(user.name)">Reset</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you pass parameter dont use ''

```
<input type ="text" ng-click="reset(user.name)">
```

**DEMO**

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.dta ="test";
$scope.reset =function(dta){
       $scope.dta = 'please enter name';
     }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
     
    <input type ="text" ng-model="dta">
     <button ng-click="reset(user.name)">reset</button>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i have used reset button onclick of that text input must reset

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$scope.reset =function(){
  $scope.user.name= 'please enter name';
}

<input type ="text" ng-model="user.name">

<button ng-click="reset()">Reset</button>
```